# Automatically comparing excel workbooks

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have two recent extracts from an old type of database, that are quite large in size and have over fifty columns. I have them in Excel spreadsheet format.

Is it a conceivable idea to utilise some form of macro within Excel that can compare two workbooks and automatically highlight any differences? If not, is it a viable idea to create a winform to do the same in C#?

Clarification: I should mention that the data in our spreadsheets contains:

- Reference numbers with symbols
- Addresses
- ints
- doubles
- strings of a large size, such that they have to be categorised as "Memo" fields in MS Access

I should also note that I don't have access to Office 2013 or 365, and cannot use the built in spreadsheet comparison tool.

Comment: you *could* try a hash compare...

Comment: They are essentially the same file, but we are still getting used to the extraction process. Since this is the case, we want to see if any data (at all) is different in the new extract. I should also clarify that the data consists of things like addresses, reference numbers, symbols...

Comment: @user1666620 I'm confused, won't this only tell me if there is a difference, and not what those differences are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used [Spreadsheet Compare](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/basic-tasks-in-spreadsheet-compare-HA102834117.aspx) in the past, it works very well.

Comment: I would have been very happy to use this, but unfortunately we only have volume licenses for Office 2010, which doesn't appear to have this tool

Comment: @MPatel You are an angel of mercy. Much appreciated, +1

Fancy adding this as an answer?

Comment: Credit should go to @Donal though. I only found this tool based on his suggestion. You should mark his answer as the correct answer! He definitely deserves it more than I do.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can take a try to [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi),which is a open source lib to operate excel.

you can open two excel file ,traversal every cell ,and compare whatever as you want .
if a cell' content is different with another , you can set  a highlight style to the both .

Answer (score 0):

As I am working with an older version of Office, [M Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548036/m-patel) suggested a tool that does the same thing as the spreadsheet comparison tool built into Office 2013 and 365. The project can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/spreadshcompare/). Please credit his comment [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24912057/3824902)